# Accessibility service click on custom view not working (performClick not overridden)

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

How to click on a custom view (iOS-style switch) from Accessibility Service in which the onTouchEvent method is overridden, but performClick not. I created a method for debugging in the service, by clicking on the views display all events in the log. When I click on all the buttons except for this custom view is displayed in the logs. It absolutely does not respond if you find the view by id and call performAction(CLICK) from AccessibilityService. I know that it is possible to use dispatchGesture and emulate swipes, but it works only with Android 7.0 (api 24). Are there any workarounds for such cases? Thanks in advance for any hints.
Config for Accessibility Service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowStateChanged|typeWindowContentChanged"
android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagIncludeNotImportantViews|flagReportViewIds|flagRequestTouchExplorationMode"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
android:notificationTimeout="100"
android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
android:canPerformGestures="true"
android:settingsActivity="com.example.helper.MainActivity"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't believe there is a workaround. Accessibility services depend on apps sharing information about the UIs they display. If apps don't expose such actions, there isn't really much you can do to recover the information.

Even with the gesture dispatch API, you don't know for sure which views are actionable.